# Can you remove air bubbles from oil by heating it just like you do with water? Does oil even have dissolved air?

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, air, gas, liquid-state

I have a flat bottle filled half with water and top half with oil. It has a impeller connected with motor which slowly swirls oil and water to create beautiful lava lamp like effect. However after sometimes oil becomes foamy. (Not an engineering question as I just explained what I did, for context)

So to resolve that I will heat water to remove air and fill bottle completely to top so there is no air inside. But I am wondering if oil also has mixed air like water and if it can be removed by heating it like water.